# how to plot a label next to the last visible value of the moving average?

Tags: label, pine-script, pine-script-v5, moving-average

I want to plot a text label next to a moving average, but i want the label to continue being shown next to the moving average while I move the chart to left

I tried

```
//@version=5
indicator("My script", overlay = true)

ema = ta.sma(close, 200)
_text = label.new(chart.right_visible_bar_time, ema, "media", style = label.style_label_right, xloc = xloc.bar_time, color = color.rgb(36, 145, 63), textcolor = color.white)
label.delete(_text[1])
plot(ema)
```

the label is shown at the last price of the moving average, but as I move the chart to the left, the label does not follow the Y average position

[how it works](https://i.stack.imgur.com/McSbP.png)

[how I would like it to work](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HKbOf.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are asking is not possible as you cannot get the moving average value of the last visible bar.

However, you can get a similar effect if you enable "Indicators and financials name" and "Indicators and financials value" from the settings.

[image]